# Output strings to arrays and output items from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sure this is really simple but I am learning Javascript and I can't figure this out.

```
 var niceDay = "please, have a nice day";
```

1. How do I create an array using "niceDay", and output the array?
2. how do I output the item in index 2?!

Answer (score 1):

Match the non-whitespace:

```
niceday.match(/\S+/g);
```

Comment: And to output element 2: `niceDay.match(/\S+/g)[2]`

Comment: Thank you Kong! I love the coding your showing me but I don't understand it. Is that Javascript? I'm soooo new to this. lol. I def need to learn this!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'split' javascript function. This will split a string on a certain character and return an array:

```
var array = niceDay.split(' ');
```

This will return an array split on each space in the string.
You can then access the second item in the array using:

```
var item = array[1];
```

Or assign the second item a new value using:

```
array[1] = 'string';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Judder! Silly question about my 2nd question thou…I want to make sure I'm on the same page. Once I use split() for my array, to get index[2] in niceDay, would I say niceDay[2];? Would the word 'have' then display?

Comment: A javascript array index is zero based meaning it starts at zero so in order to get the second item ('have') you would need to use array[1] in the array you returned from the split method. Array[2] would return the third item ('a')

Answer (score 0):

Well this should be simple, that's true

Here's a solution

```
var niceDay = "please, have a nice day";
var niceDarray = niceDay.split(' '); // splits the string on spaces

// alerts each item of the array
for (var i = 0; i < niceDarray.length; i++) {
    alert(niceDarray[i]);
}
```